# Entropy change in electric dipole alignment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electrostatics, temperature

Suppose a bunch of micron sized particles are charged positively on one half of their surface, and negative on the other. If they are arranged randomly, I understand they will have high entropy, as the system is in disorder.

If under the influence of an electric field, we shake these particles such that they align themselves (they will, right?), the dipoles are now in the state of least energy and the system is more ordered, so I understand the entropy must have decreased? Yes, not the total entropy, just the particles themselves.

Is my understanding correct, and if yes, will this bring a decrease in temperature of the particles?

Before:
[image]

After applying electric field and shaking:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If by "shaking" you mean putting the dielectric in an external *electric bias field* then yes, the entropy will decline. Specifically, the "polarization" entropy change at constant temperature will be $$\Delta S=\int_{\mathcal V} \int_0^{\mathbf E_0}\left(\frac{\partial \mathbf P}{\partial T}\right)_{\mathbf e}\cdot d\mathbf e.$$
In this equation $\mathbf P = \mathbf {P(e,}T)$ is the polarization density of the material occupying the volume $\mathcal V$  and the integral is taken at a constant temperature but the material is allowed to be temperature dependent at a fixed external bias field denoted  by $\mathbf e$ as that changes form $0$ to $\mathbf E_0$.

Comment: Woah brother :) Please explain a little more. I lack advanced physics knowledge. This "dielectric" is actually macro level, like sand particles, each half made of triboelectric materials. I shake so that they vibrate into position according to the field. The electric field is like that applied to the dielectric in capacitors.

Comment: Think of a "dielectric" as the insulator that fills the capacitor between the plates. $E_0$ is the electrostatic field intensity that is about $\tfrac{V_0}{d}$ where $d$ and $V_0$ are the plate to plate distance and voltage, resp. The polarization $P$ is the density of the polarized "molecules" aligned in one particular direction, nominally along the direction $E$ but could be off pointing in a different direction, hence the vector notation. In a simple material $P=k(T)E$ where $k(T)$ is the susceptibility and is temperature dependent, hence the "entropy".

Comment: As you increase the temperature the molecules jitter more and the alignment gets worse for a fixed bias field, that is the origin of the temperature dependence of susceptibility, and  $dk/dT$ is usually negative. Dielectric permittivity is related to susceptibility as $\epsilon = \epsilon_0 (1+\chi)$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity. (Note: In the above comment, just to confuse you, I called $k=\epsilon_0 \chi$ the susceptibility, the standard convention calls $\chi$ "the" susceptibility.)

Comment: Man, I can't thank you enough, but I only done high school maths. This calculus scares me :' ) I just wanted to know if this thing can be used for refrigeration and I have been taken for a ride. Haha! I know about the electrocaloric effect, just wanted to know if polarized macroscopic grains can be used and if yes, then how well they will work.

Comment: For the polarization density, am I supposed to use the microparticle's volume and for its dipole moment, I use the triboelectric charges on both ends of the microparticle? Is that correct? I mean these grains are my "molecules", right?

Comment: yes, there is indeed an *electrocaloric* effect that can be used for refrigeration, similar to the better known magnetocaloric effect. One such material having a strong electrocaloric response is $BaTiO_3$. My knowledge of this is very limited, a good discussion of it and also of the magnetocaloric effect is in Tribus: Thermostatics and Thermodynamics (https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015001333361&view=1up&seq=581&q1=582) but you need calculus. To calculate polarization density as local average you need a volume with a few thousand molecules in it. Learn calculus!

Comment: I thought of using two sided triboelectric microparticles so that I ensure a great dipole (only it's not on the molecular level...) as when the particles inevitably rub against each other, the halves will become oppositely charged. Do you think this will be any better at cooling than molecular level ferroelectrics, like barium titanate? Just asking for an educated guess. I guess I have some reading to do :D

Comment: ...continued.. I believe the electrocaloric effect normally relies on the molecules ability to align themselves to the field, and the larger response to an external field, the more cooling. I thought that since this is a little macro level, and we can vibrate the particles so they loosen up and progressively align up, kind of like we beat heated iron in magnetic field to align the domains. We can't really do this on a molecular level and solely rely on the molecules "wanting" to line themselves up. What do you say?